# Efficiently match the first characters of an indexed SQLite field

Tags: sqlite, optimization, indexing, full-text-search

I have two tables in SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE article (body TEXT)
CREATE TABLE article_word (
    word TEXT, 
    article_rowid INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(article_rowid) REFERENCES article(rowid),
    PRIMARY KEY(word, article_rowid)
)
```

The program stores long strings in `article.body` and, for each word in the string, it stores a lowercase version of the word along with the article's `rowid` in `article_word`.

I want to let the user search for articles by the first case-insensitive characters in a word, so a search for `baz` yields an article containing `foobar Bazquux spambacon`.

How can I modify the tables/add more (if necessary) and query them for matches optimally? Does

`SELECT a.rowid, a.body FROM article a, article_word w WHERE w.word LIKE "baz%" AND a.rowid = w.article_rowid`

take advantage of the `PRIMARY KEY` index on `article_word.word` or does it naïvely search every row?

Comment: Why aren't you using SQLite's [built-in full-text search](http://sqlite.org/fts3.html)?

Answer (score 5):

Use NSPredicate to retrive specific Attribute According to your
 requirement, and you can also do Mapping with Sqlite as in core Data.